# Xamarin.Forms で UWP プロジェクト作成時にエラーが発生する

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, win-universal-app

【解決】
[nuits.jp さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/26819/15190)の通り、
'ユニバーサル Windows アプリ用 Visual Studio Tools' がインストールされていませんでした。

プロジェクト作成から、Visual C# -> Windows -> ユニバーサル を選択して 'ユニバーサル Windows アプリ用 Visual Studio Tools' をインストールしたら解決しました。
ヘルプ -> Microsoft Visual Studio のバージョン情報 には、以下が追加されました。

> ユニバーサル Windows アプリ用 Visual Studio Tools   14.0.25219.00
>   ユニバーサル Windows アプリ用 Visual Studio Tools を使用すると、電話、タブレット、PC など、Windows 10 を実行している各デバイスで使用できるユニバーサル アプリの単一ビルドを利用できます。これには Microsoft Windows 10 ソフトウェア開発キットが含まれています。

ーーー
Visual Studio Community 2015 で、'Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable)' を選択してソリューションを作成すると、

「サブ プロジェクト 'App1.Windows' の作成中にエラーが発生しました。このプロジェクトでは、Visual Studio 更新プログラムを読み込む必要があります。プロジェクトを右クリックし、[更新プログラムのダウンロード] を選択してください。」

というエラーが表示されます。
が、ソリューションツリーに 'App1.Windows' が表示されないので、プロジェクトを右クリックできません。

なにか対策はあるでしょうか？
環境は次のとおりです。

ーーー

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
>   Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01038
>
> インストールされているバージョン:Community
>
> Visual Basic 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA609 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2015
>
> Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA609 Microsoft Visual C# 2015
>
> Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA609 Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio のパッケージ   5.205.60510.1
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11106.0 ASP.NET and Web
>   Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://www.asp.net/
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.7 Azure Mobile Services および Microsoft Azure
>   Tools で使用する共通サービスを提供します。
>
> JavaScript プロジェクト システム   2.0 JavaScript プロジェクト システム
>
> JavaScript 言語サービス   2.0 JavaScript 言語サービス
>
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4 Microsoft Azure Mobile
>   Services Tools
>
> NuGet パッケージ マネージャー   3.4.4 Visual Studio 内の NuGet パッケージ マネージャー。NuGet
>   の詳細については、http://docs.nuget.org/ にアクセスしてください。
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2 Microsoft Visual Studio
>   extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive
>   Analytics product.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60311.1 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> TypeScript   1.8.31.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
>
> Xamarin   4.0.3.214 (0dd817c) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.Android   6.0.3.5 (a94a03b) Visual Studio plugin to enable
>   development for Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.iOS   9.6.1.8 (3a25bf1) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS.

ーーー

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ユニバーサル Windows アプリ用 Visual Studio Tools

が入っていないように見受けます。
インストーラを再実行してUWPのツールキットのインストールを試してみていただけますか？